# 61.41 as a general aviator can I log training time I get from military instructors both in Military and general aviation aircrafts

Tags: faa

When I am receiving flight instruction from a military flight instructor in a military aircraft and I am not a military pilot (just have a private pilot certificate) and the instructor endorses my logbook to show training given is that allowed? Is this allowed per 61.41 sine the instructor is in a program designed to train pilots?

Comment: @757toga, I would tend to agree, but I had already drafted an answer that addresses the shortcomings in the question.

Comment: @757toga, 61.41 is beneficial for those who may not complete military flight training and be properly designated.  In such a case you can still apply the hours towards FAA ratings, the difference is you would need to pass a checkride with a DPE vs taking the written MilComp exam.

Comment: The military flight instructors are in a program specifically designated to train pilots. The regulation states that the instructor has to be in the program. It doesn’t say anything about the student. Can I have military instructors endorse my logbook showing training given when I flying a military aircraft and I’m not a military pilot, I just have a PPC

Comment: I am in the military.

Comment: James, I'm not an English major to be able to break down the sentence in the regs, but it certainly **does not *exclude* the student** from the requirement to be a part of the same training program as the instructor. Because if you remove the phrase about the instructor, *(prepositional phrase?)* it still makes sense grammatically: *"A person may credit flight training toward the requirements of a pilot certificate or rating issued under this part if that person received the training in a program for training military pilots..."* And it would seem apparent that is the intent.

Comment: If you are able to observe flight instruction, *(per your earlier question)* and swap into a pilot seat then I presume you are a crewmember on either a helicopter or transport aircraft. It's a great opportunity to observe crew coordination and get a little stick time,  *(been there, done that...)* but unfortunately I don't see a way to legally log it in your personal log book with your private pilot time.

Comment: I was curious I just log PIC time.

Comment: So, do you have a type rating in the aircraft?  What is it you fly?  (You seem to be intentionally vague...)

Comment: The aircraft doesn’t have a type rating? The aircraft is a c17. What specific question do you have?

Comment: The FAA requires that you have a type rating for large turbine powered aircraft. The military doesn’t use the same term, but obviously requires equivalent training and qualifications.  You asked if you could log it as a “general aviator” which I presume meant your GA logbook, but if you aren’t qualified in the aircraft to be legit to log PIC time in your military logbook, what makes you think the FAA would accept the time?

Comment: P.S.  If you don’t like my answer or comments I suggest you edit your question to add details about you being a qualified crewmember, (but not qualified pilot) on the C17.  I will vote to reopen and we can see what others may have to say.  Happy to make those edits for you…

Answer (score 3):

As you are aware, 61.41 allows you log military training but only as long as you are "in a program".

> (a) A person may credit flight training toward the requirements of a
> pilot certificate or rating issued under this part, if that person
> received the training from:
>
> (1) A flight instructor of an Armed Force **in a program** for
> training military pilots of either the United States or...

Whether or not your military flight instructors have FAA Flight Instructor Certificates is irrelevant as long as they are qualified by the military to teach you in the aircraft that you are flying, **AND** *you* are in a program for training military pilots.

If your friends are **not** FAA CFIs then they cannot give flight instruction in general aviation aircraft outside the military.

If they are, then they can.

It's really that simple, but you cannot randomly mix and match military and FAA flight instructor qualifications as your question seems to suggest.